# How to add a LESS class to a LESS variable?

Tags: css, less

I wrote a class in `LESS`, which looks like this:

```
.horizontal-gradient (@startColor: #eee, @endColor: white) {
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

I tried to call it inside a `LESS` variable with this:

```
@primary-color: .horizontal-gradient(#35a1e5, #0172b9);
```

However, when running I get the error

> NameError: variable @primary-color is undefined

But when I initialize the `@primary-color` as this:

```
@primary-color: #000;
```

Then it works just fine. So somehow, `.horizontal-gradient` class is causing the error.

**DEMO** *I coudn't get `LESS` working within the SO fiddle. So I created a fiddle on jsFiddle.* 
**http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/828/**

How can I use a `LESS` class inside a variable?

Comment: @torazaburo I didnt ask anything related to the browser prefixes.

Comment: What are you expecting from your `background: @primary-color;` code if the variable already contains complete rules? (aka ruleset aka "class"). It's not a problem to assign a ruleset to a variable (be it actual `@var` or a mixin - e.g. see @Shudrum answer and comments below), but you won't be able to use it the way you think you would (i.e. think of it: resulting `background: background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);` won't make any sense). So the Q is more like an XY-Problem and it's better to explain *what* you're going to achieve instead of *how* you think you'll do that.

Comment: @seven-phases-max `background: background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);` This makes complete sense now to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is not a variable, but a mixin: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature.

Without changing your .horizontal-gradient mixin, you can just use it:

```
div#background {
    .horizontal-gradient(#35a1e5, #0172b9);
    // The rest of your style
}
```

So: you cannot register a mixin result into a variable.

Comment: Because I use that variable all arround the website. With your solution ive to put that style on alot of places. Then the benefit of just editing the variable is gone.

Comment: You can create a mixin, calling another mixin, like `.gradient-background() { .horizontal-gradient(#35a1e5, #0172b9); }` Then you get the benefit of the variable again, by just modifying the `.gradient-background` mixin.